# Find the difference between total number of two different queries SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got a table `Vocab` and i want to find number of total rows and number of duplicates,this is the code i tried

`(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Vocab) - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Vocab GROUP BY Word)`
But it returned me an error `Unexpected token. (near "-" at position 29)`,How can i achieve my goal?

Comment: What do you mean by the total number of duplicates?

Comment: @GordonLinoff same rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `count(distinct)` and some arithmetic:

```
select count(*) as total_words,
       count(distinct word) as total_distinct_words,
       (count(*) - count(distinct word)) as must_be_duplicated
from Vocab;
```